# Toggle ViewController Views

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, swift3, uistoryboardsegue, uicontainerview

I am learning iOS with few sample projects. I have two view controllers in that first VC has few buttons and a mapview and the second VC has tableview showing a set of results. I have embed the both viewcontrollers in navigationViewController.By clicking a button from First VC i am able to show the tableview (using show segue) and able to go back to first VC through navigation. Now my query is I want to display the tableview (second VC) in place of one view object (map view) defined in firstVC rather than padding the tableview entirely in full screen. My problem is when showing another Viewcontroller i still want to see the few viewobjects from firstVC so I am trying to display the secondVC on top of mapview when i click on a button which triggers the segue.I have to use the single interface, so I need to load the tablview results from SecondVC into firstVC by replacing mapView's view with tableview.Please let me know your ideas if it is possible and any other ideas to achieve the same are most welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

Sreekanth Gundlapalli,

All you need to do is to add the TableView controller's view as subview to your view Controller. In order to simplify the process I personally prefer using the ContainerView,

Step 1 : Add a ContainerView to your View Controller and add the auto layout constraints to it, because your tableView will be loaded inside this container view you donate have to apply any auto layout constraint to your tableView to keep it in place :)

ex :
[image]

Step 2 : Drag an IBOutlet to the container view.lets call it as containerView :)

Step 3 : Now its up to you to have two view controller 1 for loading map and 1 for loading tableView, or you will have map view as your view controller subview and you will either hide it or remove it and add container view but I personally prefer having code clean n neat so I prefer having two different VCs

so lets create 2 VCs lets call them as viewController1 & viewController2 Savy ??

Step 4 :
lets write a method which actually loads VC and adds its view as subview to your ViewController

```
func changeEmbededVC(for status : Int) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        if status == 0 {
            mehereButton.tag = 1
            let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewController1")
            vc.willMove(toParentViewController: self)
            containerView.addSubview(vc.view)
            self.addChildViewController(vc)
            vc.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        }
        else {
            mehereButton.tag = 0
            let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewController2")
            vc.willMove(toParentViewController: self)
            containerView.addSubview(vc.view)
            self.addChildViewController(vc)
            vc.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        }

    }
```

I believe code is pretty self explanatory :D now what is `mehereButton.tag = 1` ?? Simple you want to toggle view on button press don't you :D hence I have created a IBOutlet for mehereButton and changing its tag :)

now finally in IBAction of mehereButton

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.changeEmbededVC(for: self.mehereButton.tag)
}
```

but we need to load one of the view by default isn't it :D
so change your viewDidAppear to

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    self.changeEmbededVC(for: 0)
}
```

Hope I answered your question In detail :P I know you can't neither up vote or accept answer as you don't have enough reputation :) but hope it will help somebody in future as well :)

Comment: Firstly , thanks for your answer. I am stuck at implementing it, can you please tell give me a few guide lines how to switch the mapview's view with tableview on button click without using two viewcontrollers seperately.

Comment: you can add map view and apply auto layout constraints to it and then add a tableView on top of mapView and apply auto layout constraint to that as well then have two IBOutlets one for tableView and One for mapView and in button click based on tag value hide the table or map view respectively :) thats all buddy :)

Comment: Sandeep, appreciate your pretty quick response. I think it's better if I brief you about what i am trying to implement. just like I told in my first VC I have few view objects and one among them is mapview. I have a webservice that i call each time with a location as a param i give and it gives back few results which are set of locations using which i am making annotations and showing the same in map. as i have outlet to the map in my FirstVC i can reference it and do whatever i want. If I use a container view then I can load child view (mapView) in that but how to get the outlet of it.

Comment: FYI, I have the same implemenation in my mapviewhttps://www.raywenderlich.com/90971/introduction-mapkit-swift-tutorial

Comment: Finally, able to switch the views using your idea of hiding an appropriate view and showing the other view, vice versa based on the button tag value like you directed. Thanks a ton Sandeep :).